# Adding external jars to EJB project using EAR content folder

Tags: project, ejb, ear

i have EAR and an EJB project. I noticed eclipse (sts) creates and earContent folder so I assume this is where I need to add external jars.

I added my hibernate and log4j jars on this folder but my EJB classes cannot resolve Logger class and hibernate classes.

What's the correct way of adding these jars? or should I just add them to the EJB build path?

Answer (score 9):

- Add jars to ear project EarContent folder
- In Eclipse Right click ejb project, Properties
- Deployment Assembly - Manifest Entries - Add
- Choose your jars to add, OK
- OK
- jars now added to manifest in ejb project, should work.

I'm looking at this in a project for the first time, I'd be very surprised if there wasn't a better solution to this that doesn't require Maven.  The Java EE Tools - Update EAR Libraries option looks particularly suspicious, but doesn't seem to do the above.  Note I'm on Helios still.

Comment: This answer really solved my day. I'd been looking for how to do this for hours! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add those jars under folder `EarContent/lib` *directly* , then all is done.

I.E., `EarContent/lib/foo.jar` will work but  `EarContent/lib/dir/foo.jar` won't.