# Adding External jar files in Eclipse for EAR Project

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I needed to add external jar files to a EAR Project.
I did add but the jar files are not reflecting in the lib directory, it is showing below to lib directory.
I added these jar files on right clicking on Deployment Descriptor, Import-> Java EE Utility Jar and  choosing to copy from the folder.
When I dragged the jar file on the lib directory the velocity jar file gets changed to .ear file in the eclipse project explorer.

I have attached a snapshot of the project explorer. Could you please let me know how to add external jar files to ear project as my EJB requires external jars to be included.

[image: Image of the project explorer]

I have even added classpath for jar files in my EJB manifest file 
`Class-Path: ErpServices-ejb.jar velocity-1.6.4.jar velocity-1.6.4-dep.jar xwork-core-2.2.1.1.jar`
Looking forward to your reply. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Add those jars under folder *EarContent/lib* **directly** , then all is done.

I.E., *EarContent/lib/foo.jar* will work but *EarContent/lib/dir/foo.jar* won't.

A similar question : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699876/adding-external-jars-to-ejb-project-using-ear-content-folder/16664527#16664527)

Answer (score 3):

Just try project root folder right click properties -> build path -> add external jars

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drag-and-drop, add it to the lib folder manually (outside the IDE), refresh the IDE, right-click the EAR project and in modules and dependencies, make sure that it is included in the lib folder and as a dependency.