# JBoss server error: ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

After starting Jboss server, it give me these errors.
I do some research, i know, its problem with third party library, but i dont know, how solve this.
Sorry for bad english.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."EJBTestEAR.ear"."EJBTestServer.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."EJBTestEAR.ear"."EJBTestServer.jar".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "EJBTestServer.jar" of deployment "EJBTestEAR.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class test.PDFBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.EJBTestEAR.ear.EJBTestServer.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDFont
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1811) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just few more minutes searching and finaly find corectly answer...

[Adding external jars to EJB project using EAR content folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699876/adding-external-jars-to-ejb-project-using-ear-content-folder)