# Zxing - java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation

Tags: java, ejb, zxing, ear, java-ee-7

I want to use external jars (Zxing, Batik) in my ejb bean and according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664527) I added the jars to `EarContent/lib`and everything seemed to be ok. My ejb-bean looks like:

```
@Stateless
public class ManageBarcodeBean implements ...{
    ...
    @Override
    public String createQrCode(String text, Dimension dim, ErrorCorrectionLevel errCorr) {
        ...
        try {
            ...
            if (Math.max(dim.getWidth(), dim.getHeight()) <= 1000) {
                //*
                QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
                //**
                BitMatrix bm = qrCodeWriter.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, dim.getWidth(), dim.getHeight(), hints);
                //67
                BufferedImage imgBuf = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bm);
                ...
            }
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        } 
        return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

until I add line `\\ 67` everything works fine, but adding this line yields:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError:

loader constraint violation:

when resolving method
"com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(Lcom/google/zxing/common/BitMatrix;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;"

the class loader (instance of org/glassfish/javaee/full/deployment/EarClassLoader) 

of the current class, de/lsanet/lav/address/beans/ManageBarcodeBean,

and the class loader (instance of com/sun/enterprise/loader/CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader)

for the method's defining class, com/google/zxing/client/j2se/MatrixToImageWriter,

have different Class objects for the type com/google/zxing/common/BitMatrix

used in the signature at
de.lsanet.lav.address.beans.ManageBarcodeBean.createQrCode(ManageBarcodeBean.java:67)
```

I found [this payara solution](https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/extended-documentation/classloading.html) and adding

```
<classloading-delegate>false</classloading-delegate>
```

solves the problem, but I don't understand, why accessing external jar-1 (Zxing: `core-3.3.2.jar`) at `*` and `**` works perfectly well and accessing external jar-2 (Zxing: `javase-3.3.2.jar`) at `67` does not.

I would prefer not to influence the containers class loading strategy.

Comment: Most likely you have different versions of `com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix` class in multiple jars.

Comment: I checked that, there is just one `com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix`, it is in `core-3.3.2.jar`

Comment: @tsolakp: I'm sorry, you are absolutely right. I searched the source code of `CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.java` and found in the comments `...this class is needed to allow overriding App Server's Modules / JAR files by placing them into &lt;domain_dir&gt;/lib or EAR lib directory ...` and that reminds me, that my first thought was placing the jars in `domain_dir/lib`, but then switched to `EARContent/lib`. I deleted `core-3.3.2.jar` from domain_dir, but by mistake, `javase-3.3.2.jar` remains there and causes my problem. So, your comment is the answer.

Comment: I am glad to help. You can create the answer from the comments for community if someone will have same issue or I can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

As [tsolakp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812787/tsolakp) supposed right, the reason for the `java.lang.LinkageError` were two versions of `com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix`. By mistake, I placed the same jar in `${domain_dir}/lib` and in `EARContent/lib`.